# IP addresses slip through even though IP range is in "deny from"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There's a certain company that is known for scraping contents. So I got their ip-range, let's say `44.121.131.0 - 44.121.142.255` and used `deny from 44.121` as well as `deny from 44.121.` on the root folder of my website.

But I got a view from `44.121.123.123` on `rootfolder/folder1/folder2/index.php` anyways(my website has a counter that sends an email with the current ip address whenever it is being successfully loaded).

So I put the same `.htaccess` into `folder1` and `folder2`. Still from time to time a visitor shows up from within a denied IP-range.

Has my server been hacked? What is still wrong?

Full .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://server.com/403.html
deny from 44.121.


ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
```

Answer (score 0):

To effectively block all IPs starting from `44.121.` use this rewrite rule in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^44\.121\.
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I used this with my own ip and it did not block me.

Comment: This rule works pretty well. Make sure this is placed as **first rule in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`** and you access your website as `http://domain.com/` If you are trying `http://domain.com/folder1` then .htaccess in `/folder1` will need this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your original concept for allow/deny here is the correct .htaccess code:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 44.121.
allow from all
```

This states that all traffic is allowed before it is denied.
Do deny traffic from 44.121.
Allow traffic from everyone else.